# mod_auth_cas.so: undefined symbol: SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth

Tags: apache, certificate, mediawiki, ubuntu-18.04, cas

We are trying to use CAS server with mediawiki on apache in ubuntu. We add .so file in right place and we did everything tutorial said on web. But when we try to restart apache service we got bellow error:

apache2: Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/cas.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_auth_cas.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_auth_cas.so: undefined symbol: SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a dependency for `mod_auth_cas` is missing, and that dependency is `mod_ssl`. Make sure it is loaded by Apache prior to line 146 of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.